# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION.oops Php

Tags: php, runtime-error

am new to oops in php. this is my first oops program. this program is so basic(form program) but i can't figure out what is tat i have to do.
Sorry if this is a newbe question, but I am new at this.
am getting the error as 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /ni.class.php on line 34
line34 :$str=$ab->startform('#','post','myform').'

'.

```
              <?php
    class ni
    {

    function startForm($action='#',$method='post',$id=NULL)
    {
    $str="<form><action =\"$action\" method=\"$method\"";

            if(isset($id))
            {
            $str.="id =\"$id\">";
            }
    return $str;
    }

        function addlabel($id,$text)
        {

        $str= "<label id=\"$id\">$text hello </label>";
        return $str;
        }

    function addInput($type,$name,$value)
    {
    $str="<input type=\"$type\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"\>";
    return $str;
    }

        function endForm()
        {
        return "</form>";
        }

         $ab=new ni();
         $str=$ab->startform('#','post','myform').'<p>'.
                       addlabel('label','amtext')
                     .addinput('text','input1','value1').'</p>';
         echo $str;
         $ab->endform();



    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This is why indentation is important.

Comment: Your indentation is terrible. First make the code human-readable, then you might be able to make it parser-friendly.

Comment: -1 Parse errors aren't appropriate to post to stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move this

```
$ab=new ni();
$str=$ab->startform('#','post','myform').'<p>'.
addlabel('label','amtext')
.addinput('text','input1','value1').'</p>';
echo $str;
$ab->endform();
```

Outside of your `ni` class

---

Basically like this

```
class ni {
  function startForm() { ... }
  function addLabel() { ... }
  function addInput() { ... }
  function endForm() { ... } 
}

$ab=new ni();
$str=$ab->startform('#','post','myform').'<p>'.
addlabel('label','amtext')
.addinput('text','input1','value1').'</p>';
echo $str;
$ab->endform();
```

---

More commonly, as classes are intended to be reusable, you will see this separated into multiple files

```
// classes/ni.php

class ni {
  function startForm() { ... }
  function addLabel() { ... }
  function addInput() { ... }
  function endForm() { ... } 
}

// somefile.php
require('classes/ni.php');
$ab=new ni();
$str=$ab->startform('#','post','myform').'<p>'.
addlabel('label','amtext')
.addinput('text','input1','value1').'</p>';
echo $str;
$ab->endform();
```

---

As a final recommendation, I would change the usage to be like so

```php
$ab = new ni();
<?php echo $ab->startform('#', 'post', 'myform') ?>
<p>
  <?php echo $ab->addLabel('label', 'amtext') ?>
  <?php echo $ab->addInput('text', 'input1', 'value1') ?>
</p>
<?php echo $ab->endForm() ?>
```

Comment: Or more concisely, use `<?= ...` instead of `<?php echo ...`

Comment: Eric, sure, that's a fine suggestion; just know it's not safe bet on `<?=` being available by default before PHP >= 5.4

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, corrected script should look like this:

```
<?php class ni {

    function startForm($action = '#', $method = 'post', $id = NULL) {
        $str = "<form><action =\"$action\" method=\"$method\"";

        if (isset($id)) {
            $str .= "id =\"$id\">";
        }
        return $str;
    }

    function addlabel($id, $text) {

        $str = "<label id=\"$id\">$text hello </label>";
        return $str;
    }

    function addInput($type, $name, $value) {
        $str = "<input type=\"$type\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"\>";
        return $str;
    }

    function endForm() {
        return "</form>";
    }

}

$ab = new ni(); $str = $ab -> startform('#', 'post', 'myform') . '<p>'
. addlabel('label', 'amtext') . addinput('text', 'input1', 'value1') .
'</p>'; echo $str; $ab -> endform();

?>
```